# .NET C# to PHP via local TCP connection slow

Tags: c#, php, .net, sockets, tcpclient

I have a .NET C# console application acting as a client and a PHP script acting as a server. Both connect via `localhost` so there is no internet speed dependency. The problem I have is that when my client app sends a binary file, say only 100KB, it takes around over 30 seconds to complete. I expected this process to be just about instantaneous.

Here's some code:

.NET client app:

```
public bool SendToServer(string data)
{
    data += "DONE"; // Terminator string
    TcpClient tcp = new TcpClient(this.serverURL, this.serverPort);
    NetworkStream stream = tcp.GetStream();
    byte[] b = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
    int len = b.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        stream.Write(b, i, 1);
    stream.Flush();

    Console.WriteLine("Sent to server {0}", Convert.ToString(b) + " len: " + b.Length);
    return true;
}
```

PHP server script:

```
class ImageService
{
    public $ip, $port, $soc;

    function Listen($ip, $port)
    {
        $this->ip = $ip;
        $this->port = $port;

        $this->soc = stream_socket_server("tcp://".$this->ip.":".$this->port, $errno, $errstr);
        if(!$this->soc) Out($errno);
        else
        {
            Out("created socket");
            $buf = "";
            while($con = stream_socket_accept($this->soc))
            {
                Out("accepted socket");

                do{
                    $buf .= fread($con, 1);
                    if(strlen($buf) == 0) break 2;
                }
                while(substr($buf, -4) != "DONE");
                $buf = substr($buf, 0, strlen($buf) - 4);

                switch($buf)
                {
                    case "quit":
                        break 2;
                }

                print '<img alt="image" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$buf.'">';
                $buf = "";
            }
            fclose($con);
            fclose($this->soc);
            Out("Closed connection");
        }
    }
}
```

Calls:

```
set_time_limit(0);
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
$is = new ImageService();
$is->Listen("127.0.0.1", 1234);
```

Comment: You should write entire array at once rather than one byte at a time.

Comment: You're writing one byte at a time, which doesn't help. Why don't you just use `stream.Write(b, 0, b.Length);`? Also your protocol will fail if your string ever contains "DONE", and can't handle non-ASCII characters, but that's not a speed issue...

Comment: More importantly, binary files are not ASCII.  Don't use strings unless you actually have text.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am potentially sending across image files that may be a few MB, if there is no issue doing as you say then I'll certainly change the code. Also, if I do it one byte at a time I can measure the progress against the total length. SLaks I assumed ASCII would make the binary safe for transfer, is this not the case?

Comment: @Lee: Well 100,000 one-byte calls is definitely not as nice as a single 100K-byte call, particularly when you already *have* all the data in memory. And on the ASCII front, no, it's certainly not the case. If you're trying to transfer binary data, you shouldn't make your method accept a `string` parameter at all. See http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2013/06/21/but-what-does-it-all-mean.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having looked at your PHP code, I *suspect* this is actually the cause of the speed problem:

```
do{
    $buf .= fread($con, 1);
    if(strlen($buf) == 0) break 2;
}
while(substr($buf, -4) != "DONE");
```

Assuming that PHP works the same way as Java and .NET (i.e. assuming that `.=` creates a new string containing a copy of the previous data), you're creating a new string for every single byte... that's an O(n^2) operation, which is going to get nasty really quickly.

Additionally:

- Your protocol is broken if you have "DONE" in the original data
- Your protocol specifically deals with *text*, not binary data. It's possible that you're base64-encoding the binary data first (given the PHP) but that's inefficient too. If you've really got binary data, it's a good idea to transfer it *as* binary data. Sockets are entirely capable of doing that - there's no reason to get text involved *at all* unless your problem domain specifically requires text.

I suggest you write the length of the data to the socket first, as a 4 or 8 byte integer (depending on whether or not you think you'll ever need to transfer more than 4GB). Then you can read the length first in your PHP code, allocate an appropriately-sized buffer, and then keep reading from the socket into that buffer (reading a large chunk at a time) until you're done. That will be much more efficient *and* won't have the protocol issues mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help Jon. I understand the terminal sequence is very basic, however it serves as a temp solution at the moment til I have it working as expected. Your assumption regarding base64 encoding is true also, great tips.

Comment: @Lee: If you're using base64, then you're *not* sending a binary file as per your description - and you're also inflating the size of data transferred. Unless you're using a transport which is inherently text-based, I wouldn't use base64. By all means base64-encode the data *at the PHP side* so that you can include it in your response; that's a different matter. Anyway, hopefully the explanation about the repeated string concatenation has done the trick.

Comment: Just a little snag I now have is that sending binary to my PHP script results in the PHP error `A non well formed numeric value encountered` when it gets to a certain point in `fread()`

Comment: @Lee: Well you need a bit more diagnostic information before we can really help with that. I suggest you ask a new question, as it's beyond the scope of "why is this so slow" at this point.